# How do I map a virtual path in windows ce HTTPD Web Server?

Tags: asp-classic, windows-ce

Here the situation.

I need to map http://some ip address/getSettings to path Windows\www\wwwpub\getSettings.asp

I am doing this on a Windows CE device using the HTTPD Web Server, and I would need to set something in the registry, but I am not sure where and how.

Should I create a "Subkey" /Inventory under /VROOTS or /WebSites/VRoots?
Then what type of register do I use? Will string do?
What is the value name and data?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You should create the mappings under 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\COMM\HTTPD\VROOTS
as described here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee499756.aspx
But you can map only folders, not single files as you are asking.
If you want to just strip the extension you may need to write an ISAPI filter.